# Open .exe form from .dll form?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 projects.

- `MyLib` its compiled `.dll`
- `MyApp` its compiled `.exe`

`Mylib` has `form`, and `MyApp` has `form`.
So there are 2 forms.

`Mylib form` is login form with 2 `textboxes` for login and password and `Login` named Button!
`MyApp` form should be opened after you enter correct data to `MyLib login form`.

Also `Mylib form` has cases, so when you click `button` it will show,

- Case 1 - `Messagebox` with wrong username
- Case 2 - `Messagebox` with wrong password
- Case 3 - It should open form from `MyApp`.

How do I do it?

Comment: Why is the login form in a `dll`?

Comment: I need only how to open that form from MyApp since i got everything else done. And I was searching over internet for it and could not find anything related about opening .exe form from .dll form button :)

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to your .exe and accessing the form class from it?

Comment: @OneFineDay It's in the .dll since I'm trying to create login system. I mean I'm almost done just to figure out this problem how to open another form from .dll form.. And I know I'm lazy there will be much more like me to make over and over same login form for each application im creating so its much easier to put it into .dll and then i can obfuscate .dll and no one wont have access to it for cracking easy and so on..

Comment: @Cory i can access from .exe to .dll form, but i need to access from .dll form to .exe form ? Understand what im trying to say?

Comment: @Cory We are going now offtopic :)

Comment: @user3385780: You can add the .exe as a reference. VS has supported this since 2005. Better yet, move all of the code you want to share to one DLL, and reference everything from one place. What you're doing seems like a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: I will compile .dll and share it over with others so if i add reference to my .exe then it wont work if they use .dll to protect their app with .dll login ..

Comment: your EXE can run without showing a form; it could call the login service in the DLL and when it gets the OK, continue on and do whatever it does.

Comment: Yeah but also if user just click X on form to close it it will open mainform from exe so its not good...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to do this since you cannot reference your DLL and have it reference your EXE as well.

1. The simple way, based on your example is to call the form in your DLL modal from your EXE. Then you know when it is closed/hidden and you can read properties or whatever you want.
2. If the modal option will not work for you, you need to add an event in a class in your DLL that you EXE can handle (ADDHANLDER or WITHEVENTS). Then in your DLL, fire the event and in your EXE handle the event.

Comment: Can you show me the best solution trough code or over teamviewer?

Comment: Here is some good info on modal forms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358.aspx     And here is some good info on events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx

Comment: I knew that already but it did not help me :/
Would it work maybe if I do something like `dim myform as new form` and then in Exe to call dll.myform as Mainfrom or something?

Comment: If you want to do the modal way, in your EXE, you would do something like this: Dim MyForm as new MyLib.LoginForm  and then to show it you would do shomething like this: MyForm.ShowDialog.  The very next line will be what happens after the MyForm is no longer visible so you can read variables or properties or whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: If you just want to know about success/failure, use the "DialogResult" of the modal form.